# gwt celltree changing image when the node is open/closed

Tags: image, gwt

I have drawn a tree with CellTree using GWT 2.5, and when opening the node I want to change the image before the text in the cell. I tried do with ImageResource but don't worked because I don't want change the icon, just the image in the cell container, it is possible to do that in CellTree?

Example in the same node when is open and closed:
+ [image] A
- [new image] A

```
public void render(Cell.Context context, TreeNode value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) { 
    if (value instanceof TreeNode) { 
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div><img src ='/bound.png' width=16 height=16><span class=\"treeElements\">"); 
        sb.appendHtmlConstant(value.getName() + "</span></div>"); 
    }
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can you post the code you used for rendering your cells in the `CellTree` ?

Comment: My code is:[CODE] public void render(Cell.Context context, TreeNode value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value instanceof TreeNode) {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div><img src ='/bound.png' width=16 height=16><span class=\"treeElements\">");
        sb.appendHtmlConstant(value.getName() + "</span></div>");
    }[/CODE]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it:

1. Check in the render method if the node is open (check the `CellTreeNodeView` class how to do it) and conditionally render the corresponding image.
2. Use the `cellTreeOpenItem()` obfuscated classname (it will get set on the Cell when you open it) and CSS selectors to change the image (but then you will probably use background image instead of an img element).